# How to add Product id after cart url on cart page in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite

I want to add some product id after cart url on cart page the product that is added in the cart. Because i want to target that products by using omnisend extension that target by part of url. To show popup on cart page showing discount for that particular product.

**Second method** - there's second method is if all products in cart have discount, then there must be a random url key after cart url in url on cart page, so that i can target one specific part of url to show popup of discount on products at cart page that are added in cart on cart page only.

Answer (score 0):

Julius from Omnisend here. I recommend you contact our support team (by logging to your Omnisend account and clicking the Chat icon in the bottom left corner).

Maybe they will give you some ideas on how to resolve this (also, to better understand your needs).

Cheers